# Problem with flashing project code to CC2541 chip (using CCLoader)

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy, iar

I have followed the project

https://github.com/rampadc/cc254x-hidKbdM

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4Qql.jpg

which could turn the HM-10 Bluetooth module into a bluetooth mouse to control smart phone

but the LED on HM-10 was not blinking (if the flashing process is successful it will blink)
after I flashed the code

#### steps

1. build project and export hex file on IAR embedded testbench
2. use hex2bin tool to convert .hex file into .bin file

command: `hex2bin.exe HM-10_CC2541_Experimental.hex`  the output a binary file

3. upload ccloader code to my Arduino UNO board
   (ccloader link:https://github.com/RedBearLab/CCLoader)
4. connect wire like this post
   (https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4Qql.jpg)
5. the flash the code

command:`CCloader.exe 5  HM-10_CC2541_Experimental.hex 0`

(format： CCloader.exe [com port] [.bin file] [0:is default setting UNO board] )

#### Result

[Result pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LJtb.png)

and the LED on HM-10 was not blinking

my Android phone cannot discover the device

and the HM-10 cannot response to the serial port monitor in Arduino IDE.

I have not idea what can i do now

Comment: As per info in link https://github.com/rampadc/cc254x-hidKbdM  device operates in 2 modes: command mode and translation mode. Your device is in which mode ?

Comment: Also try flashing with pre-built hex files.

Comment: The hex file was failed to upload to the CC2541 chip, so  I'm not able to know the device is in which mode 

Comment: But I tried the pre-built hex files, it works will